# A way to neaten this PHP code

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php

//code above    
$pic_1 = $afil['image_1'];  
$pic_2 = $afil['image_2'];
$pic_3 = $afil['image_3'];
$pic_4 = $afil['image_4'];
$pic_5 = $afil['image_5'];
$pic_6 = $afil['image_6'];
$pic_7= $afil['image_7'];
$pic_8 = $afil['image_8'];
$pic_9 = $afil['image_9'];
$pic_10 = $afil['image_10'];

if ($pic_1 = "")
{
$pic_1 = //defaultpic - to be defined, same as below
}

if ($pic_2 = "")
{
$pic_2 = //defaultpic
}
?>
```

Rather than repeat these "if" statements for each picture (up until $pic 10) i just wondered if somebody could point out a more elegant and efficient way of doing it.  I am quite new to php and this is a new situation i have encountered.  Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think you might want a foreach?

Comment: You should probably review the manual pages on [control structures](http://php.net/language.control-structures).  There, you will find information on how to construct loops using `while`, `for` and most interestingly here, `foreach`.

Comment: Use arrays more effectively.  Change your array keys to `$afil['image'][1]` and loop over the `$afil['image']` array.

Comment: This is a good question; maybe the code you're starting with isn't the best, but that's how you learn. I don't understand why someone would downvote your question. But then, everything here is being downvoted rampantly, so... maybe someone hates PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `arrays` and loop through them with just 1 `if` statement, like this,

```
 foreach($afil as $k => $v) {
  if(empty($v))
    $afil[$k] = ...//default pic
 }
```

Or, if you are keen to have an additional array `$pics` (for future use maybe),

```
foreach($afil as $k => $v) {
  $pics[$k] = $v;
  if(empty($v))
    $pics[$k] = ...//default pic
 }
```

Also, `=` is an assignment operator. For comparison (or condition check), you need to use `==` or `===` (type safe).

**Edit:**

```
 $afil = mysql_query(...);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($afil)) {
  //In here, say you create an array $result_rows with all the rows
  $result_rows[] = $row;
 }
```

Then, use `$result_rows` in the foreach.

Comment: I'm about 60% sure that if you want to change `$v` within the loop and have it reflected in the original array, you'll want to make it a reference.  Like `foreach ($afil as $k => &$v) {`

Comment: i get an invalid argument? for the "foreach" function.  Any idea why?

Comment: sorry same applies to you.  I'll see if your edit works.  Cheers

Comment: still says my argument is invalid?

Comment: do a `print_r($afil);` right before the loop and see if `$afil` is indeed an array, and all its contents are as expected.

Comment: i get absolutely nothing on that.  I probably should point out that $afil = mysql_query.....(in which i am selecting a row from mysql).  After which i was then trying to define the local variable as shown above and that was when i wanted a neat way of looping through them.  Still $afil is an array isn't it?  So don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: There you go :), `$afil` is a resource, and NOT an array, if its assigned as `$afil = mysql_query(...)`. I will edit my answer on how to loop through in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is your golden solution:

```
$pic = array('image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3'....);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($pic); $i++){
if ($pic[$i] == ""){
$pic[$i] = //defaultpic - 
}

}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the suggestion.  Firstly i changed the 'image_1" and so to "$pic_1" because "image_1" was coming from a mysql_query.  Anyway according to your code the following should be correct shouldn't - $pic[0] = $pic_1 = "uploads/default.png".  I then have in the right html tag <img src = "<?php echo $pic_1; ?>"...(width etc)...but nothing is coming up.  Is my equality assumption above wrong?